# Changing range of numbers in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I am doing SVD in Python, the range of my data index is 150,000 to 160,000. Because of this SVD is getting very resource intensive. How can I change the range of this data to  0-10,000 while maintaining duplicates.

```
Eg: i have consecutive data points   :150001,150001,155003,156004,157005

it should map to  :1,1,2,3,4
```

Such that the range shrinks, and i dont have to hand a higly sparse data martrix.

My primary requirement is that i need to map data such as (169,169,256,945,3445,9999) transforms into (0,0,1,2,3,4)

Comment: It sounds like the answer here is just "subtract 150000". If you need help with subtracting 150000, we're going to need to see more context.

Comment: As  user2357112 mentioned: `remapped_data = [num-150000 for num in data]`

Comment: Scipy has sparse matrix functions.

Comment: im using sparsesvd, but before i pass data into it, i need to convert it into a sparse matrix, and that is not happening with the data of this dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code records the indices of the unique numbers in the list of numbers in rank order:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> v = [169,169,256,945,945,945,345,9999]
>>> np.hstack([0, np.cumsum(np.diff(v)!=0)])
array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4])
```

Please update the question to reflect these requirements.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could use `rank(method='dense')` on a Series [(docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [150001,150001,155003,156004,157005]})
>>> df
        a
0  150001
1  150001
2  155003
3  156004
4  157005
>>> df["a_rank"] = df["a"].rank(method="dense").astype(int)
>>> df
        a  a_rank
0  150001       1
1  150001       1
2  155003       2
3  156004       3
4  157005       4
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small function for this, am hoping there is a simpler way to do the same.

```
def range_minimizer():
    ind=0

    for i in d1.index:
        if i==0:
            d1['new_index']=0

        else:
            if d1['movie'][i]==d1['movie'][i-1]:
                d1['new_index'][i]=ind
            else:
                ind+=1
                d1['new_index'][i]=ind
```

FYI my data looks like this

```
   user   movie  rating
0     1     169     2.5
1     1    2471     3.0
2     1   48516     5.0
3     2    2571     3.5
4     2  109487     4.0
```

After running this function on the data i get the final result:

```
   user   movie  rating  ind
0     1     169     2.5    0
1     1    2471     3.0    1
2     1   48516     5.0    2
3     2   48516     3.5    2
4     2  109487     4.0    3
```

Comment: Huh? Does this have anything to do with your question? Where's the 150001 stuff?

Comment: im giving you another example of my data. although the data is different, the point remains the same.

Comment: Why did the movie column change? Did you mean to do that?

Comment: forget everything, my requirement is that i need to map data such as  (169,169,256,945,3445,9999) transforms into (0,0,1,2,3,4) . Thats it.

Comment: I think this assumes that the data is sorted by movie number.

Comment: But look at your original movie column vs. your output movie column, it changed. Why? Your comments and output seem to be in conflict. And ErikR is right, your solution assumes a sort.

Comment: @ErikR : yes it does. ive passed in a sorted dataframe.